# Does Microsoft Edge with IE mode require IE to be installed?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The new Chromium based version of Edge has a feature described as [Microsoft Edge with IE mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode). The documented [Microsoft Edge with IE mode prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#prerequisites) only specify minimum OS versions and a Microsoft Edge administrative template. What is not listed is if the OS needs to have Internet Explorer installed for IE mode to work.

Does an OS have to have Internet Explorer installed to use Microsoft Edge with IE mode?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, as this is not something I have tested.  However, more than likely, the answer is yes.

As you are probably aware, Internet Explorer was replaced by Edge.  In that transition, much of the old, unused, and insecure functionality was *not* moved to Edge.  In order to access that functionality for legacy purposes, you had to [install Internet Explorer as a Windows 10 feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026136/windows-10-use-internet-explorer).  With the move to a Chromium base, there is no logical reason to think that functionality will be added.  I would think the IE Mode would work similarly to the Chrome extension "[Open in IE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-ie/looohpideggedchhpphemdmppnmdkgfd?hl=en),"  which launched Internet Explorer as a tab in Chrome.